# Getting quantity and price of a specific item drupal ecommerce

Tags: php, drupal, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I'm trying to create an offsite payment module in drupal using ecommerce.
I need to find the quantity and price of a specific product.
Product1Quantity
Product1Price
Product2Quantity
Product2Price and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the order_id of the order(s) you are looking for. You can do this with an sql query.

Once you have the order_id, then you can load the order with `commerce_order_load($order_id)`

See: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.module/function/commerce_order_load/7

When you have the $order object(s) you can explore them with `echo "<pre>"; print_r($order);` and I am sure all of the variables you need will be in there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i wound up doing.

```
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$quantityAndPrice = array();

foreach ( $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item_wrapper )
{
    $quantityAndPrice .= round($line_item_wrapper->quantity->value()) ."";
    $quantityAndPrice .= $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount->value();
}
```